# Carbon 14 in Coal

Tags: geology

The [creationist video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6tJbvtIYCV0) claims Carbon 14 should not be found in layers older than 90 000 years old, and yet researchers found some, and concluded it was evidence of a global flood.

> In 2003 a group of researchers performed an unusual test on 10 coal samples obtained from Pennsylvania State University. The researchers wanted to see if carbon-14 could be detected in the coal samples. This test might be considered 'unusual' because carbon-14 decays relatively fast, and should not be detectable after a maximum of 90,000 years. Yet the coal samples tested came from strata allegedly ranging in age from 37 million to 318 million years.

Are the claims made in the video correct? or are they erroneously interpreting the results of the experiment?

I believe this question may be directly related to

- [Is Carbon-14 found in all strata?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23671/is-carbon-14-found-in-all-strata)
- [Is carbon-14 still increasing in the atmosphere?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5993/is-carbon-14-still-increasing-in-the-atmosphere)

Comment: The first question you pointed out is the same question; the accepted answer names the paper that this video is based upon. Given you still had a question, I am wondering if there is a reason you don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: also related to my still-unanswered question here: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/rate-of-underground-formation-of-carbon-14-by-neutron-capture